# Get session value and display it in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using a color picker and when any user change the color a `ajax` function is call which get that value and store it in php `session` and also return that value. Now i want that store value in `session` so that when user refresh the page the value remain there. My all code is here

```
function colorbg(){
            var colorbg = $( "#colorbgi" ).val();
            //alert( colorbg );
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "ajax_set_color.php",
              data: { colorbg: colorbg }
            })
              .done(function( msg ) {
                  //alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
                  var newbgcolor = <?php echo '#'. $_SESSION['colorbg']; ?>;
                  $(".search_form, .nav-tabs li a").css("background-color", newbgcolor);

              });

            }
```

And the php page code is here, in this page session is store.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['colorbg']) && $_REQUEST['colorbg'] != "")

{

  $_SESSION['colorbg'] = $_REQUEST['colorbg'];
    $colorbg = $_SESSION['colorbg'];

    print $colorbg;
}
```

Now guide me where i am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Have you started the session ?

Comment: yes i start the session

Answer (score 0):

You missed at start of your php-script:

```
session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

you want get the color here, as you set it from the session value, when the page is loaded:

```
var newbgcolor = <?php echo '#'. $_SESSION['colorbg']; ?>;
```

it should look like this:

```
var newbgcolor = msg;
$(".search_form, .nav-tabs li a").css("background-color", newbgcolor);
```

if you want to set it on load, do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".search_form, .nav-tabs li a").css("background-color", "<?php echo '#'. $_SESSION['colorbg']; ?>");
});
```

or directly into the form like this for example:

```
<form class="search_form" style="background-color:<?php echo '#'. $_SESSION['colorbg']; ?>"> ...
```

Comment: But if i use it like this then when user refresh the page the value is not there that's why i want to get value from session.

Comment: The directly putting style is not suitable for me, because i have to changes the color on lot of places, the 2nd one is not working i already try it. But not working.

Comment: ok. if you tried the sec. from me, i didnt had quots.. try again with this: `.css("background-color", "<?php echo '#'. $_SESSION['colorbg']; ?>");`, otherwise check the sourcecode, it should look like this: `.css("background-color", "#yourColor");` when the page is renderd...

Answer (score 0):

```
function colorbg(){
            var colorbg = $( "#colorbgi" ).val();
            //alert( colorbg );
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "ajax_set_color.php",
              data: { colorbg: colorbg }
            })
              .done(function( msg ) {
 alert(msg); // it shows session colorbg

              });

            }
```

**and in php**

```
 session_start(); //write also here
if(isset($_REQUEST['colorbg']) && $_REQUEST['colorbg'] != "")

{

  $_SESSION['colorbg'] = $_REQUEST['colorbg'];
    $colorbg = $_SESSION['colorbg'];

    print $colorbg;
}
```

Comment: i start the session its just functional code not entire code.

Answer (score 0):

```
function opt_val(a,b)
    {
        if(a==3)
        {
    var role=a;
    var dept=b;
    if(role=="role")
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(dept=="dept")
    {
        return false;
    }
    //alert(dept);
    //alert(role);
    //alert(opt_value);
    try
    {
        ob=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        try
        {
            ob=new ActiveXObject(Microsoft.XMLHTTP);
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            try
            {
                ob=new ActiveXObjcet(Msxml2.XMLHTTP);
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                alert("your browser does not support");
            }
        }
    }
    ob.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(ob.readyState==4)
        {
            var arr=$.parseJSON(ob.responseText);
            //alert(arr);
            if(arr[0]==1)
            {
                $('#popup_001').show();
                $('#popup_003_inner_message').html(arr[3]);
                $('#popup_001_inner_message').html(arr[2]);
                $('#popup_002_inner_message').html(arr[1]);
            }
            else if(arr[0]==0)
            {
                window.location="register.php";
            }
            else if(arr[0]==2)
            {
                alert (arr[1]);
            }
        }
    }
    ob.open("GET","dept_chk.php?dept="+dept + "&role="+role,true);
    ob.send();
        }
            //sheet='+sheet + '&fname2='+fname2+'&col='+col+'
            return false;
    }
```